# Is there anyway to view the data rate per packet or packet transmission duration? - Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet

I am trying to find a way to log and display the data rate per packet or packet duration. The goal is to line this up with a software defined radio recording, so I do not necessarily care about average bandwidth or bits in one second. I care about the symbol rate or how long the packet transmission physically lasts. Is there a good way to do this?

I have already tried adding a column in preferences with field "radiotap.vht.datarate.0" but this did not work.